# Automate HTTP POST/GET PHP on file download using header & readfile

Tags: php, python, authentication, download, webautomation

I developed a PHP script to deliver a file after an authentication.

```
<?php #SERVER.PHP

if (isset($_REQUEST['uname']) && isset($_REQUEST['passwd'])) {

    if ($_REQUEST['uname']=='a' && $_REQUEST['passwd']=='a')   {

        session_start();
        session_regenerate_id();        
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fake_name.pdf');
        readfile('original_name.pdf');        
    }
}
?>

<form name="login" action="test.php" method="get">
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname"> <br />
    Password: <input type="text" name="passwd"> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Hence I want to automate the login and download process, initially I tried using wget to download the file(fake_name.pdf):

```
$ wget "http://1.1.1.1/server.php?uname=a&passwd=a"
```

but it downloaded a file with content

```
<form name="login" action="test.php" method="get">
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname"> <br />
    Password: <input type="text" name="passwd"> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

I could able to download file "mask_fname.pdf" While accessing from a web browser is working perfectly fine.

Then I tried writing python script to get the file, I am getting only HTML content.

```
#py1.py
import httplib, urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({
    'uname' : 'a',
    'passwd' : 'a'
    })
headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           "Accept": "text/plain"}
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("10.1.1.2:80")
conn.request("GET", "/mdh/test.php?uname=a&passwd=a",
             params, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
print response.status, response.reason
data = response.read()
print data
conn.close()

#py2.py
import urllib
import urllib2
url = 'http://10.1.1.2/mdh/index.php'
form_data = {'uname': 'a', 'passwd': 'a'}
params = urllib.urlencode(form_data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params)
data = response.read()
print data
```

But the output was same for all my tries. Is there any other way to do that. Is there any other approach to automate the download of file(fake_name.pdf) with given username and password, apart from web browser automation(link python::splinter, selenium)?

Ultimately, I need to automate a file download from a server using HTTP with authentication.

Comment: General recomendation is to use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) over urllib. You'll probably run into less issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I see no indication of any HTTP redirection occurring as suggested in your question title - certainly not initiated in the PHP code that you have posted. Why do you think redirection is occurring?

I think that the problem is in `server.php`. Does `original_name.pdf` actually exist and is it readable by `server.php`?

Note that the HTML form will *always* be included in the response, even when the correct credentials are supplied. This is because the PHP script does not terminate after `readfile()` - it continues on, emitting the HTML form.

For this reason I suspect that `readfile('original_name.pdf')` is not producing any output, and is probably because the PDF file does not exist, or is inaccessible to the script.

Here is a modified version of your `server.php` which corrects the problem:

```
<?php #SERVER.PHP
if (isset($_REQUEST['uname']) && $_REQUEST['uname']=='a' &&
    isset($_REQUEST['passwd']) && $_REQUEST['passwd']=='a') {

    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=fake_name.pdf');
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    readfile('original_name.pdf');
}
else {
?>
<form name="login" action="" method="get">
    Username: <input type="text" name="uname"> <br />
    Password: <input type="text" name="passwd"> <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Note that I have added a header for `Content-type: application/pdf` - this will help browsers to properly render the PDF content. Also, the form `action` was submitting to `test.php`, so I have removed that and now the form will be submitted back to `server.php`.

Both of your python scripts look OK.